# ReactJS: IE11 not making new HTTP request, using cached data

Tags: reactjs, http, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, cache-control

I am facing issues in my React application on `IE11` where the UI is not hitting backend services for every new request and returning the response from cache data. The application works fine on Chrome.

In case of IE the services end with code : 304 instead of 200. 
PFB the request headers:

```
Accept  application/json,*/*
Request GET /services/v0/search/?uid=12900 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type    application/json
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

PFB the response headers obtained on `IE`:

```
Response    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
x-frame-options DENY
x-xss-protection    1; mode=block
x-content-type-options  nosniff
```

Any  clue, what could be the reason behind IE rendering such behaviour? TIA

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could try adding the "Pragma" header:

```
headers: { Pragma: 'no-cache'}
```

also mentioned here : [Axios only called once inside self-invoking function (Internet Explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830531/axios-only-called-once-inside-self-invoking-function-internet-explorer/45835054#45835054)

Comment: thanks much, it worked. I however read the docs and found that pragma is only for HTTP 1.0 clients but as per my request headers I am on HTTP 1.1. Then why do I need to use Pragma, Cache-control should have worked.

Comment: @Manu I believe the server does not properly handle cache-control. That might be your issue. Using pragma is basically the same (from a client's perspective) since it is used as a fallback. You can read more here, this is what i got from it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

Check this header in your http request :

**Cache-Control:**

`no-cache` :
Forces caches to submit the request to the origin server for validation before releasing a cached copy

`no-store` : 
The cache should not store anything about the client request or server response.

`must-revalidate` (`Revalidation and reloading`) :

The cache must verify the status of the stale resources before using it and expired ones should not be used

`Expires`: 
0  -the resource is already expired

Comment: Hi, added the header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store') to my request but it still uses cache!

Comment: Please share request and response header

Comment: ```headers: { Pragma: 'no-cache'}``` should work. ```Pragma``` is the HTTP/1.0 implementation and ```cache-control``` is the HTTP/1.1 implementation of the same concept.

Answer (score 2):

Should client side solutions not work as a last resort you could try setting the headers on server side.
If you were using `node` and `express` you could write a middleware which would add the headers for desired routes for you, that could look something like this:

```
function cacheMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    // Should work for detecting IE8+
    if (req.headers['user-agent'].includes('Trident')) {
        res.set({
            'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
            Pragma: 'no-cache',
            Expires: new Date('01.01.2000'),
        });
    }
    next();
}

router.get('/', cacheMiddleware, (req, res) => res.send('content'))
```

Idea for the solution from [link](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/777#issuecomment-74585938)

Comment: Thank you!!! I added pragma no cache to my API requests from the browser but was still getting cached data. Adding this middleware to my express server finally got it working.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same issue where the IE11 simply ignores the get request to the backend server. The quick way I found to fix is to pass one unnecessary param with the get request, in our case, a timestamp.

```
const t = Date.now(); 
axios.get(`${API_DOMAIN}/api/bookingep/find?c=${t}`);
```

Because every time the timestamp is different, the ie11 does send out the get request as expected.